# HTML can't loop the music

Tags: html, embed

here is my code 
it seems that i cant loop the music, any idea?

```
<embed name="lostmojo" src="music/Loving.mp3" loop="true" hidden="true" autostart="true">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) tag might help you

Comment: can u explain a bit more abt using audio tag? thx!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: <audio controls loop>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>  Try this..

Answer (score 0):

Does the music play at all?  I had problems getting it to play using Firefox.  If it doesn't play at all, the problem may be due to the `hidden` attribute, which has spotty support among browsers.  If you remove the `hidden="true"` does it work?

If this is the case, try using CSS to hide the element.  Something like this:

```
<embed name="lostmojo" src="music/Loving.mp3" loop="true" autostart="true" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
```

That seemed to work for me.  The test audio I used looped correctly in Firefox.