# I am trying to loop an embeded mp3 file on my page. I got the sound working, however I am having issues getting it to loop. Please Assist?

Tags: html, css, loops, audio, autoplay

I am trying to loop the sound file and am having trouble finding a solution.

```
<embed class="audio" src="D:\Sublime Text 3\first\Clock-ringing.mp3">
```

Comment: Try replace <embed class="... with <audio loop class="...

Comment: Or here [HTML can't loop the music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881141/html-cant-loop-the-music#20881654)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I tweaked it so that to hide the controls and autoplay.

```
 <audio controls autoplay loop>
   <source src="D:\Sublime Text 3\first\Clock-ringing.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio> 

<style>
    audio {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Instead of saying thanks, it is appreciated to accept one of the given answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `audio` tag:

```
 <audio autoplay loop>
   <source src="D:\Sublime Text 3\first\Clock-ringing.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

```
<embed class="audio" src="D:\Sublime Text 3\first\Clock-ringing.mp3" loop="true">
```